# Google Play Campaign Measurement Refferer param, does it count if downloaded later without parameters?

Tags: android, google-analytics

[This](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-how) is the specific thing I'm talking about:

If somebody clicks my google play link with a referrer param, but then they go back later and download the app (the query params won't be there anymore).

Does it still count as a referral in the analytics?  Will the broadcast still be fired to the app?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by putting an app up on Google Play and trying it out.

For anybody who finds this and is wondering, the answer is yes.  A user can click your Google play link with a referrer parameter, close it, and then come back later without the referral param and the download still counts as a conversion.